# Color Formats for input surface in video encoder

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, video-encoding

I am developing a video encoder using low level media codec API. I am using surface for input and output. As per the media codec library it says that if you are using surface you can use `COLOR_FormatSurface` and `COLOR_YUV420Flexible` as color format.

I understand about `COLOR_YUV420Flexible` as it follows 4:2:0 chroma subsampling, but I am confused about `COLOR_FormatSurface`. what is it, how many bits does it occupy? I couldn't found any thing on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Using `COLOR_FormatSurface` you can use a canvas of a surface to draw frames on it.

Also you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28029613) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68286941/12629252) answers.